# Grouped query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I try to get my products in different panels base on their category id, instead i get them all together.

**Note:** before i get to codes i need to explain that my products **are not** connected to my categories directly instead they get `subcategory_id` and subcategories will get `category_id` anyway, I managed to get my products by their category id and **all i need now is to group them by that category id**.

## Codes

`AppServiceProvider`

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
    $category = DB::table('admin_designs')
                      ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'admin_designs.category_id')
                      ->join('subcategories', 'subcategories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                      ->join('products', 'products.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
                        ->get();

    $view->with('category', $category);
});
```

`blade(view)`

```
<div class="container">
      @foreach($category as $sc)
      <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                  {{$sc->title}}, <u><b>cat:</b></u> {{$sc->category_id}}, <u><b>sub:</b></u> {{$sc->subcategory_id}}
            </div>
      </div>
      @endforeach
</div>
```

PS: basically what it has to do is to get each products to separate panels by their category ID.

## Screenshot

[image: screen1]

## UPDATE

I changed my query to:

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
            $category = DB::table('subcategories')
            ->join('admin_designs', 'admin_designs.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
            ->join('products', function ($join) {
              $join->on('subcategories.id', '=', 'products.subcategory_id');
            })
            ->get()->toArray();

            $view->with('category', $category);
        });
```

Now I can get my products but still I cannot get them by `groupby` in order to group them base on their category.

## UPDATE 2

I managed to get my data as I wished except i cannot get category title in my loop which is important to me.
Here is my `blade` code:

```
@foreach($category->groupby('category_id') as $key => $value)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              @foreach($value as $ki)
                              {{$ki->title}}, Cat: {{$key}}, Sub: {{$ki->subcategory_id}}<br>
                              @endforeach
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

this is how it looks like:

[image: screen2]

> Now what i need is to get `categories title` as title of each panel.
>   but if i use `$ki->category->title` or `$key->title` etc. i get error.

any idea?

Comment: Use `groupBy` on your resultant collection: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby

Comment: @btl i tried it didn't work! probably i made the wrong group-by.

Comment: `$view->with('category', $category->groupBy('category_id'));` doesn't do it?

Comment: @btl Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @mafortis show us your `dd($category)` after group by

Comment: `$category` is going to be split up into subgroups after calling `groupBy`, so your blade file is going to need to change.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby. That shows the structure and using `->toArray()`. so update the looping in your view accordingly

Comment: any idea on new updates?